# looping the which() function over a list of dataframes with lapply

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a problem in R looping the which() function over a list of dataframes. I need to replace all the numbers >1 with 1.
Here is my code.

```
mylist_b <- lapply(mylist_a, function(x){
                                          x[which(x>1)] <- 1
                                    })
```

Here is one of my dataframes of mylist_a

```
                                       D1           D2         D3
a                              0.68659264 1.047092e+01  1.0009219
b                              0.02358574 7.992743e-04  0.3253237
c                              5.23294642 1.130614e+01  5.6566890
d                              2.86947631 7.860165e+00 15.0000000
e                              8.09922178 8.196586e+00 15.0000000
f                             15.00000000 1.500000e+01  1.8389688
```

When I run my code, I get mylist_b, but it is a list of numeric vectors with only one value per each vector.

```
> mylist_b$dataframe_a
[1] 1
> class(mylist_b$dataframe_a)
[1] "numeric"
```

Instead when i run the which() function on each single dataframe it works fine

```
mylist_a$dataframe_a[which(mylist_a$dataframe_a>1)] <- 1
```

here is the result

```
                                       D1           D2           D3
a                             6.865926e-01 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
b                             2.358574e-02 7.992743e-04 3.253237e-01
c                             1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
d                             1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
e                             1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
f                             1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
```

can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work if you return `x` back

```
lapply(mylist_a, function(x){
    x[x>1] <- 1
    x
})
```

A different alternative is to use `pmin`

```
lapply(mylist_a, function(x) pmin(as.matrix(x), 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is also to use `replace`

```
lapply(mylist_a, function(x) replace(x, x > 1, 1))
```